# date constraint validation not working for xlsx using apache-POI in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

Hi I am trying to create a date constraint validation in xlsx file using apache-POI in java.
Following is the code I am using.

```
XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(spreadsheet);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint constraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint)dvHelper.createDateConstraint(OperatorType.BETWEEN,
                    "25/10/2014", "30/10/2015", "dd/mm/yyyy");
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0,0,0,0);
                XSSFDataValidation dataValidation = (XSSFDataValidation)dvHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList);
dataValidation.setShowErrorBox(true);
dataValidation.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
spreadsheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```

But it is not working. When I try to edit the value, except for that value it doesn't let me change the value. It's as if validation is for that particular value.

When I open the file, in the data validation section, validation is showing as follows:

[image]

And now if I remove the "=" sign from start date and end date then It works.
Please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String dateFormat` is simply ignored in [XSSFDataValidationHelper.createDateConstraint](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_16_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataValidationHelper.java?revision=1791046&view=markup#l48). So simply the strings "25/10/2014" and "30/10/2015" were putted into the formulas instead of Excel dates.

Do

```
DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createDateConstraint(OperatorType.BETWEEN,
                    ""+DateUtil.getExcelDate(sdf.parse("25/10/2014")), ""+DateUtil.getExcelDate(sdf.parse("30/10/2015")), "");
```

instead.

There `DateUtil` is `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil` and `sdf` is `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class DataValidationDateBetween {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();  
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

   DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
   DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createDateConstraint(OperatorType.BETWEEN,
                    ""+DateUtil.getExcelDate(sdf.parse("25/10/2014")), ""+DateUtil.getExcelDate(sdf.parse("30/10/2015")), "");
   CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);            
   DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);

   validation.setShowErrorBox(true);

   sheet.addValidationData(validation);

   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("DataValidationDateBetween.xlsx"));
   workbook.close();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks axel, it worked. But this same thing works for HSSF. So I thought it would work for XSSF as well.

Comment: Yes, [HSSFDataValidationHelper.createDateConstraint](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_16_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDataValidationHelper.java?revision=1791046&view=markup#l40) does not ignoring the given `String dateFormat`.